# Batch renaming files to a more meaningful name

Tags: batch-file, zip, unzip

Soon I will begin receiving nightly zip file uploads that information will need to be renamed to make it more meaningful. Each night a zip file is uploaded and will be labeled similar to `CallRecording_1-000.zip`. Once extracted, it will contain the following set of files:

```
index.html
index.xml
AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458932.2.WAV
AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458948.4.WAV
AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1607458983.6.WAV
```

The XML file contains the following:

```
<all>
  <recording_index recapp_id="" recapp_name="" last_generated="0">
    <day_index date="2020-12-08">
      <recording target_name="Unknown recording" filename="warning%3A" filesize="0" date="1969-12-31 19:00" source="" destination=""/>
      <recording target_name="1+ Dialing (11 Digits)" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458932.2.WAV" filesize="26K" date="2020-12-08 15:22" source="Softphone Test4" destination="15545595331"/>
      <recording target_name="1+ Dialing (11 Digits)" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458948.4.WAV" filesize="45K" date="2020-12-08 15:23" source="Softphone Test3" destination="15559639584"/>
      <recording target_name="10 Digit Dialing" filename="AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1607458983.6.WAV" filesize="59K" date="2020-12-08 15:23" source="Softphone Test4" destination="9545596535"/>
    </day_index>
  </recording_index>
</all>
```

What I am looking to do is convert the series of file names to a combination of the tags shown above.

**Desired Output**

`AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458948.4.wav` should be renamed to `date_source_destination.wav`. Based on how the date's format includes "forbidden" text for a file name, `source_destination.wav` would be sufficient unless there would be a way to convert the date format to `mm-dd-yyyy`

**Example of final output based on example above:**

`AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458948.4.wav`**=** `2020-12-08_Softphone Test3_15559639584.wav`

For the intents and purposes of simplicity. I am generating a bat file that will create at temp directory labelled `ExtractFolder` that will later be renamed with the date of the upload.

Comment: sure you want to skip the time information?

Comment: Preferably not as it will help to further identify the call information. I see that you replied with a script that includes the date, is there a way to convert the time so it can appear in the filename as well?

Comment: that's just a marginal adaption. See my edited answer.

Comment: Don't forget that phone numbers can contain * character and in case of SIP URIs - any character. I prefer using filesystem-safe base64 variant in file names. This is why there is separate XML file in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%z in ("ExtractFolder\AT1*.WAV") do (
  for /f tokens^=4^,8^,10^,12^ delims^=^" %%a in ('type "ExtractFolder\index.xml"^|find /i "%%~nxz"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%t in ("%%b") do (
      ECHO ren "%%z" "%%t-%%u_%%c_%%d%%~xz"
    )
  )
)
```

Output:

```
ren "ExtractFolder\AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458932.2.WAV" "2020-12-08 15-22_Softphone Test4_15545595331.WAV"
ren "ExtractFolder\AT1_ID1_TT3_ID2-1607458948.4.WAV" "2020-12-08 15-23_Softphone Test3_15559639584.WAV"
ren "ExtractFolder\AT1_ID1_TT3_ID6-1607458983.6.WAV" "2020-12-08 15-23_Softphone Test4_9545596535.WAV"
```

NOTE: I "disarmed" the `ren` command by just echoing it. Remove the `ECHO` when you are sure it does what you want.

NOTE: This highly depends on the formatting of the `xml` file, which is not guaranteed. If you think, the format might change, better switch to a language that can parse `xml` properly (batch can't)